# Is it any good Video player for react-native rather then ... react-native-video

Tags: react-native, react-native-video

```
<Video
    source={{
      uri:
        'VID',
    }}
    style={styles.video}
    controls={true}
    resizeMode={'cover'}
    paused={paused}
    selectedVideoTrack={{
      type: 'resolution',
      value: 360,
}}/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React Native doesn't have a *Video* component, so you may well be using Expo

```tsx
import { Video } from 'expo-av'; // https://docs.expo.io/versions/v40.0.0/sdk/video
```

Otherwise react-native-video is a great go-to choice for vanilla (non-Expo) React Native apps, we've been using for years commercially too.

We implemented caching with async-storage, but seems it's also at least [partially supported](https://github.com/react-native-video/react-native-video/blob/master/docs/caching.md).